# Kind of normal distribution generator

Tags: c++, normal-distribution

I have one question. I need for documentation kind of this normal distribution generator. I found it and works fine. What is it? This isnt a reversing of distribution, or Monte Carlo method. I dont know this method.

```
double Class::  normal(const double mean, const double std)
{
    static const double pii = 3.1415927;
    static const double r_max = RAND_MAX + 1;
    return std * sqrt(-2 * log((rand() + 1) / r_max))*sin(2      *pii*rand() / r_max) + mean;
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that it works fine?

Comment: I made a histogram from 10000 samples, its enough for my needs

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a [Box-Mueller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) to transform uniform RVs to a normal one